# Has a retargetable disassembler been used successfully for a word-oriented mainframe architecture?

Tags: mainframe, software-recommendation, disassembly

Among many modern [disassembly/reverse engineering tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler#Examples_of_disassemblers), has any been used to disassemble legacy code for a word-oriented mainframe, preferably with a non-power-of-2 word length, like [CDC 6600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_6600) (60 bit) or [PDP-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-10) (36 bit)? If so, is there an existing open source example of a plugin implementing such an architecture?

(While some may infer a request for opinion from the above, please keep in mind that the phrasing of the question makes it a question of fact.)

Comment: "Modern disassembly tools" is a bit vague, do you mean more than simple disassembly? `simh` has (very simple) in-built disassembly of all supported architectures, including those with a non-power-of-2 word. And non-power-of-2 words are not a problem, as you'd extract the binary in question and provide it as a file on a modern computer, using some power-of-2 word big enough to embed the non-power-of-2 word. Radare2 has in open [issue](https://github.com/radareorg/ideas/issues/293) to implement a PDP-10 plugin.

Comment: Fixed-length instructions seem to be particularly easy to disassemble, the only issue being to decide whether some words are code or data, but then again to some extent it "doesn't matter" if you accidentally decode data as code; the human can usually see what happened.

Comment: @dirkt I mean also some analysis of the control flow, assigning labels to instructions to which a branch/jump can be made. The trick here is that addressing is done per word rather than per byte, and not every instruction can be addressed (there could be several instructions per word). Thank you for the link; I guess it is not that straightforward if the issue is pending since 2018.

Comment: @another-dave For reverse engineering, telling code and data apart is substantial. You don't want to spend time decoding garbage instructions or providing manual guidance to the disassembler for every literal.

Comment: I dunno - in my limited experience (mainly PDP-11 stuff) you just look at the dump and say "that ain't actually code" since it makes no sense.  Side-by-side code, octal, and ASCII helps.  Possibly this only works with sufficiently rich architectures, Maybe I couldn't do it with MIPS r2000 code output by a compiler.

Comment: @another-dave Figuring out that something is not a code is usually straightforward; the problem is, for example, when an address is assigned to a register before calling an error message routine, and at the address there is garbage code in the disassembled output rather than a neat text, or there is garbage code instead of a floating point constant, etc. Modern reverse engineering tools can reason about the code to a great extent.

Comment: http://simh.trailing-edge.com/ , https://github.com/FSword7/ts10

Comment: @BruceAbbott I don't think you're responding to the question I've asked. Please see, by following the link in my post, what advanced reverse engineering tools like Ghidra, IDA, or Radare2 do.

Comment: "assigning labels to instructions to which a branch/jump can be made." Keep in mind that the analysis those tools provide is vastly more helpful for code that is the output of a modern compiler. With hand-crafted assembly code that's typically for, say, the PDP-8 (and probably the PDP-10 as well, I've less experience with this code), most of the tools will fail hard. And I am not even sure how well they'll be able to deal with the output of compilers at that time.

Comment: "Several instructions per word" isn't that hard, just extend the concept of an address type (though that may need changes in the tool itself).

Comment: @dirkt Those tools are able to deal with hand-crafted code for contemporary architectures. Granted, they will not be able to figure out the calling convention of the subroutines, but figuring out code and data by smart reachability analysis, and marking the jump targets, including the targets of indirect jumps, they should be able to do.

Comment: And as for the PDP-10 ticket, I'd assume the reason it's not done is not that it's not straightforward (though you somehow seem to be fishing for that kind of response), it's just a lot of work - the PDP-10 instruction set isn't really small.

Comment: And maybe your experience with those tools is different from mine, but from my experience with using them, if I look at typical PDP-8 code with data declarations mixed in at the end of the page, and a calling conventions that mix code and data, I'd still say they'll fail hard. They'll be somewhat useful, but I would still need to do lots of hands annotations. But maybe you have more experience with that than I do.

Comment: _"I don't think you're responding to the question I've asked. Please see, by following the link in my post, what advanced reverse engineering tools like Ghidra, IDA, or Radare2 do."_ - if you have a specific need for Ghidra, IDA, or Radare2 plugins then you should put that information **in the question**, not expect us to divine it from a bare link. Your 'disassembly/reverse engineering tools' includes Debug and SIMON, which are hardly 'advanced reverse engineering tools'. But you wanted source code for disassemblers, which my links provide (in a comment because it's not an answer).

Comment: I am struggling to understand what your goal is here. Obviously you don't have any specific 'word-oriented mainframe' code that needs to be disassembled, so why the interest in whether any such plugins exist? FYI I am writing an interactive disassembler right now so I have a pretty good idea what is involved, but I don't have any inclination to produce plugins for unfamiliar platforms that are uninteresting to me - which is essential for getting the best results from these tools.

Comment: I do have code that needs to be disassembled (i. e. restored to a maintainable assembly language program), and plenty of it. I was able to decompile several Pascal programs for the BESM-6, including the Pascal compiler, by pattern matching and iterative re-compilation, but the OS for the BESM-6 is written in the assembly language. I'm interested in seeing prior work for similar CPUs (actually, the 48-bit CDC 1604 would be the closest to it) to estimate and compare the amount of work required to write plugins for various tools.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I work for Hex-Rays.

The [IDA Pro by Hex-Rays](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/processors/) supports disassembly of several processor families with “wide instruction words”, for example:

1. PDP-11 (16-bit instructions)
2. PIC (12-, 14- and 16-bit instruction sizes)
3. Various DSPs from AD, TI and Motorola (generally 16 to 48 bits)
4. Itanium (VLIW, 128-bit instruction bundles)

(There are probably more that escape my mind at the moment.)

It was also used to handle an esoteric ISA called cLEMENCy specifically invented for a CTF (capture the flag) contest, with a **9-bit** byte size and middle-endian byte order:

https://github.com/cseagle/ida_clemency

In short, if IDA does not handle it, you can probably write a module to do it.

Comment: Around 600,000 PDP-11s of all models were sold, making it one of DEC's most successful product lines. The PDP-11 is considered by some experts to be the most popular minicomputer. [Wikipedia] Is there a relatively big demand for the PDP-11 dissassembler, even today, because of this?

Comment: @SingleMalt I don’t know how many people actually make use of PDP-11 support but there are probably some. It’s just one architecture of many supported by IDA.

Comment: Thanks, understood. Does IDA work with Transmeta VLIW core binaries, or is this too esoteric?

Comment: @SingleMalt there’s no standard support and I haven’t seen any third party code but I imagine it’s not impossible to add.

Comment: I believe I would be able to; I just want to compare the amount of work required to add a processor to various available tools. The example is quite instructive; as "bytes" of up to 32 bit are supported, for a 48-bit architecture with 24-bit instructions declaring the byte size to be 24 should work.